# DP problem with maximizing sums with special step rule

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am stuck trying to do this DP problem.

You have an array of cities with the number of lemons they are selling each. You can skip `S` or `S+1` cities. `S` always starts at 1 and you can always do `S+1` at the beginning. You are trying to find the most lemons you can buy.

For example,

Input:

```
1 2 2 4 5 8 3 15 1
```

Output:

```
23
```

You visit cities 0, 2, and 4, then decide to skip two at a time, visiting city 7 last.

I'm a beginner in the concept of DP and was wondering how you would go about solving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic House Robber problem. Here's [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlvhyfcoQa4) for youtube video with code and explaination.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because the link could break or the video may be taken down in the future. It is recommended to add enough explanation to the answer to make it useful by itself.